# How to obtain $\int_{0}^{1} x(1+x^2)^n dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^{2k+2}}{2k+2}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis

While solving the integral for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ I have got the following result $$\int_{0}^{1} x(1+x^2)^n dx=\int_{0}^{1} x \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{2k}dx= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{2k+2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{1}{2k+2}  =\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2(n+1)}$$

However, the last step I only got through online evaluations of both the integral and the sum. What theorems or methods does one have to use to obtain the result from the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $u=1+x^2$, $du=2x \, dx$, and it reduces to the integral of $u^n$.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the sum of a geometric series for the last step?

Comment: @AbeautifullTheorem One can use $$ \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k+1} $$ (write out the factorials to check that) and then apply the Binomial Theorem again to refactor into $2^{n+1}-1$. I don't think the geometric series applies directly.